# CSS: position texture at bottom of DIV

Tags: css

Need the blue and yellow boxes to sit on the bottom within the yellow. In other words shift them down. been fighting this for hours.

[image]

```
#customer { overflow: hidden; background: yellow;}
#address-title { width: 450px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; background: blue;}
#address-one { width: 450px; height: 80px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; background: red;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="customer">

        <textarea name="address" id="address-title">Customer Invoices</textarea>
        <textarea name="address1" id="address-one"></textarea>
        <img src="images/green-plus.png" class="lookup-cust-plus" id="look"/>

        <table id="meta">
            <tr>
                <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                <td><textarea form ="testinsert" id="invoice_num" name="invoice">20170212</textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td form ="testinsert" name="date" class="meta-head">Date</td>
                <td><textarea id="date">February 12, 1965</textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
                <td><div class="due">$0.00</div></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

</div>
```

results of recommendation:
[image: Flex Example changes]

Comment: share your html code too so we can see what is best option

Comment: Use Inspect element and see does these divs have margins. Use `margin-top` on `address-title` to bring it down.

Comment: ok, adding `margin-top: 25px;` makes the container taller?

Comment: You've got a couple issues. Your `img` element breaks your table convention since it's not in a cell, that will cause you issues especially cross-browser. Second, you'll need to [clear](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) your floats...but really if you're looking for responsiveness there's better ways.

Comment: There are also some issues with your HTML. `form` is not an attribute but a tag in it's own right. `img` is not a vaild child of `tr` it should be outside the table or in a `td`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to make some changes in the HTML and use flex to style the layout.

In my solution, I divided your layout into 3 elements under the customer element. Set the customer to `display:flex` so it will be easy to order the 3 major section in a row. Each major will place itself according to `align-self` property. `flex-end` will place the elements at the bottom of the container.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

#look {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  align-self: center;
}

.space {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#customer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: 140px;
}

#address-title {
  width: 450px;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#address-one {
  width: 450px;
  height: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#meta {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:first-child {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div id="customer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="space"></div>
    <textarea form="testinsert" name="address" id="address-title">Customer Invoices</textarea>
    <textarea form="testinsert" name="address1" id="address-one"></textarea>
  </div>
  <img src="images/green-plus.png" class="lookup-cust-plus" id="look" />
  <table id="meta">
    <tr>
      <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
      <td><textarea form="testinsert" id="invoice_num" name="invoice">20170212</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td form="testinsert" name="date" class="meta-head">Date</td>
      <td><textarea id="date">February 12, 1965</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
      <td>
        <div class="due">$0.00</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: that's going to alter too many factors in my code and don't want to throw flex into the mix at this point. I have moved the img outside the table - really looking to just float to the bottom. margin-top works a little, what about locking the container to fixed height?

Comment: In my opinion it's better to use a more robust solution rather than looking for the short and ugly solution. Your case is simple and you should use a good layout in order to make your life easier once you'll want to maintain the code

Comment: alignment of recommended flex produced the changes above? (see edit today)

Comment: did you remove the `flex-direction: column;` from the `container` class?